# MOSFET transistor replacement for Proform T7 Treadmill

Tags: transistors, mosfet, replacement

[image: Transistor I believe is blown]Treadmill motor turns for a second and immediately stops. After researching issue, looks to be a blown IRFP250M
IOR P039J 20 8J.

My question is, I'm having trouble finding a replacement that includes the numbers after the IRFP250M. Are those numbers important or are they simply related to a specific manufacture. Any recommendations on a replacement?

Best Regards,
Billy

[picture of transistor]

Comment: How did you conclude that the MOSFET is broken? If it runs for a second, an open MOSFET is unlikely.  Break out your DMM and set it to diode mode and see if you can measure the body diode.

Comment: Good question! I'm not 100% sure it's the transistor. Mostly process of elimination and online research helped me come to this conclusion. I connected a DC battery to the motor and the motor successfully ran as expected. I found that a bad transistor is a common issue amongst people with the same symptoms so I thought I'd give it a try. I believe it all started with the deck/walking belt needed to be aligned as it would stop randomly. My teenage son continued to force walk which forced it from randomly stopping to completely stopping. It was a birthday gift for my wife:-(

Comment: Here's a video that helped me come to the conclusion that it could be the transistor. https://youtu.be/-swFm5uI6pw

Comment: after installing these, did your treadmill work?? my proform 2000 is giving me the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [data sheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRFP250M-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015356287bc71fda) indicates that the P means lead free. The rest on that line is a date code The lower line is an assembly lot code. These numbers can be ignored.

You can find IRFP250M on-line although Mouser and Digi-key appear to be out-of-stock.

Infineon makes these now so check their website for sales info.

Comment: Wow! Thank you Russell for the response! I appreciate the detailed recommendation... I'm checking out Infineon now.

Comment: Thanks again Russell. I just ordered 3 and they will be here later in the week.

Answer (score 0):

The [IRFP250M datasheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRFP250M-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015356287bc71fda) specifies on page 8 the TO-247AD part marking information (using the IRGP30B120KD-E as example):

[image]

In your case the markings `P039J` (lead-free + date code + assembly line), `20` (assembly lot code) and `8J` (not specified) aren't relevant. And `IOR` is simply International Rectifier's logo.

Many datasheets (at least those of reputable brands) contain a 'Marking' section that'll help you identify parts.